# Как правильно поставить запятые? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

Боже дай мне разум и душевный покой принять то что я не в силах изменить мужество изменить то что могу и мудрость отличить одно от другого.

Comment: Бог всех людей наделил разумом, и не только. Возьмите Молитвослов: там точно найдёте то, что Вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Боже (обращение), дай мне разум и душевный покой принять то, что я не в силах изменить(придаточное), мужество изменить то, что могу(еще придаточное), и мудрость отличить одно от другого.